# Simple Python API for Django Project

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a (Django) website where users can upload CSV files that are stored in a "protected" directory (i.e not in /media/, so users can only access their own files). I'd like to write a Python package that lets users access their files from within Python scripts. What is the best way to go about doing this?

The requirements are essentially: (1) the user "logs in" using their credentials, (2) they can get a list of their files as a string, and (3) they can give a file name and get a Pandas dataframe as output.

From the point of view of the user, the code might look something like this:

```
import my_api

# User logs in
con = my_api.connect(user="jim", password="password")

# Print list of file names
con.list_data()

# Get pandas dataframe for "File_Name"
df = con.get_data(filename="File_Name")
```

I don't know if something like the Django Rest Framework is appropriate given my limited requirements. I just need to log the user in, and then two urls/views that "recognize" a user is logged in and pass back the required data.

Comment: This isn't really as simple as you think. For example, what would `con` actually consist of? How would it manage the user's logged-in status, and send it back in the subsequent calls?

Comment: Presumably, con would retain user and password as class instance variables and would re-send them for every operation.

Comment: I was hoping I could do something like submit the username and password via a post request to each of the API's urls/views. So `con.list_data()` would post the username and password to www.mysite.com/api/list-data etc.

Comment: @JohnGordon - that's correct.

Comment: The `requests` package allows you to make repeated http-requests using the same session. If you keep that session object in `con`, you shouldn't have to resend login credentials each time

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using JWT. One endpoint `/api/login/` would take `username` and `password` in the payload authenticate the user and return a JWT. The JWT can contain a `pk` (`pk` to make it simple for now) of the user (and many more if you need). Other endpoints like `/api/list_data/`, `/api/get_data/` or `/api/data/123/` would need to have the Authorization header with `JWT jwt.from.api_login`. It would decode the JWT take the user `pk` from it's payload and with that know which user is requesting.
The `my_api` client could look like:

```
import requests


class MyApi(object):

    base_api_url = 'http://myapi.local:8000'
    _token = None

    def _login(self, token):
        self._token = token

    @property
    def _auth_header(self):
        if self._token is None:
            raise Exception('fetch the token first!')
        return {'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(self._token)}

    def call_login(self, username, password):
        response = requests.post(
            '/api/login/', json={
                'username': username,
                'password': password,
            }
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        self._login(response.json()['token'])

    def call_list_data(self):
        response = requests.post(
            '/api/login/', headers=self._auth_header
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        return response.json()
```

It's just my approach - I don't like sessions I like REST and JWT's.
Using Django REST Framework (along with restframework jwt) could help but you may be good on your own.